# Is the same functionality guaranteed across the different vesions of the same jar?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, dependency-management

I am rebulding an old java-ee application with maven. It has very old dependencies which have newer versions. If I include the newer deps the project does compile but, will I have problems regarding functionality?

For example with javax.ejb, the project had this dep and checking arround I´ve found it was last modified at 2001. If I include this dep [maven dependency link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/ejb-api/3.0) that I know its been updated, will I have the same functionality?. In other words: will the behaviour of the application change despite it does compile with the newer dependency versions?.

edit:
This is just an example, the project has more deps: org.apache.axis

Thanks

Comment: All versions of the EJB specification and EJB API are backward compatible.  Nearly all specifications and public APIs from Oracle/Sun are backward compatible;  it's always been a design goal.

Comment: Are you asking about different versions of the EJB specification, or about different versions of third party packages?

Comment: The question is related to different versions of third party packages. As far as I know one key desing principle in Java library is that it should be backward compatible, but I dont know if it applies to different ejb implementations/verisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot be sure that the functionality is the same.  The Interfaces and Classes may be named the same, but at runtime you have no idea what will happen.  Libraries try to keep things backwards compatible, but you'd have to read the release notes for each past release in order to be sure.  Even then, some minor thing may have not been included in the notes.  Your best bet is to track down the original dependency.

That being said, you may as well try running it if it built successfully!

Comment: Although, to address the point @VGR made in the comments above, some providers tend to be more stable in their backwards compatibility.  It's really something you have to address on a case by case basis.